# How to use Tor via VPN and with help of bridges?

Tags: configuration, bridge, censorship, vpn

When I tried to use Tor with VPN it worked at my home network but when I tried at my university it can't open as they have blocked Tor so I have to use VPN which I'm sure they haven't  blocked, but when I Try to execute Tor didn't start.

Comment: I thought to use bridges but i have no idea what to put in address and port option and which to decide out of httphttps/sock4/sock5.Please help me out